# How do I use Unix to delete a file named "*"?

Tags: unix, command-line

My father just told me a story about a colleague of his who had nearly finished his thesis, and was flying to Denmark on a plane to discuss it with a friend. He was playing around on his computer, and had created a file named "*.tex". When the flight was nearing its end, he wanted to delete the file, so he told Unix `rm -rf '*.tex'`, and deleted his thesis by accident. How do I avoid this, other than not creating files that are named `*`?

Comment: This is why I keep my thesis under version control (i.e., git).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just escape the '*' by adding a preceding '\'. `rm \*.tex` works perfectly. Also, never `rm -rf` anything unless you're really sure of what you're doing.

The r and f stand for [r]ecursive and [f]orced. That means, if you target a directory with that command, it will immediately and irretrievably delete that directory, all its files, and all subdirectories and all their files, and so on until the end of the tree.

Comment: I agree that -rf is extremely dangerous.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to single quote it correctly. Try this for yourself:

```
$ mkdir tmp
$ cd tmp
# Create a file named '*.tex', containing the string 'foo'
$ echo 'foo' > '*.tex'
# Create a file named 'bar.tex', containing the string 'bar'
$ echo 'bar' > 'bar.tex'
$ ls
$ rm '*.tex'
$ ls
```

Answer (score 1):

```
rm -i \*.tex
```

The `-i` is for interactive; you get to say yes or no to each file deleted; it is the antithesis of `-rf`.  The backslash prevents the star being expanded, so you should only be offered `*.tex` and not `thesis.tex` too.  You could use quotes around the name to — in this case, single or double quotes will work.  If the special character was a back-tick or a dollar sign, you'd need single quotes.

If you are in the slightest bit worried about which file name(s) might be deleted, then using the interactive mode can be useful.  If you use `rm -fr`, you have to be sure that it will do what you want (you're in the correct directory, the wildcards will do what you expect).  If you're logged in as root when you run it, you need to stop and think twice before hitting return; a mistake can be deadly.

I'll also observe that if the thesis was not under version control and not backed up, then the colleague was living dangerously.  If it's important, back it up (and put it under version control if at all possible).

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to mitigate human errors or hardware/software failures damages on file systems is to have a reliable backup process in place.

However, doing backups while flying on a plane is not specially practical but now that copy-on-write file systems like ZFS and btrfs supporting lightweight snapshots are getting more and more popular, having a daemon handling regular snapshots would have saved the thesis.

Answer (score -1):

The question at the end of the anecdote was "How do I avoid this".

If you want to avoid ever accidentally deleting a file, you can alias the `rm` command as follows (add this line to your startup script):

```
alias rm='rm -i'
```

This will ensure that every time you delete a file, you will be asked "are you sure"?

Of course, all the other answers about escaping '*' are valid - but this is your "sure fire catch all" trick.

Different shells have slightly different syntax - so see what you need...

Comment: Aliassing the `rm` command sounds like a good idea, until you find out that the alias is not in effect and what you relied on to be the alias actually isn't the alias, and the file gets deleted.  There are many ways in which the alias can be 'missing'.  If you must do it, use a command name such as `del` to be an alias; then if the alias is missing, nothing dangerous happens.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - can you give an example of that ("the alias is not in effect")? I agree that teaching yourself to always use del instead of rm adds an extra layer of protection - as would clearing the w bit on all files you care about... "Use backups" has been, and always will be, sound advice.

Comment: (1) You normally use `bash`; you find yourself on a machine where you've been given `ksh` to work with, so your `.bashrc` file is ignored by `ksh`. (2) You're on someone else's machine; you haven't installed your `.bashrc` file on the machine yet.  Etc.  Lots of ways...

Comment: "on someone else's machine". Suddenly I don't care so much if I'm deleting files. :-)

Comment: Remind me never to let you anywhere near any machine I work on.  I don't mind if I mess up my own stuff; it is a serious problem if I muck up someone else's stuff — very serious.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - of course you are completely right. I had my tongue firmly in my cheek...

Comment: In addition to Jonathan's right comment about aliasing `rm` to `rm -i` being a bad idea in general, it would also be totally useless in this particular case. Appending `-rf` to `rm -i` would just disable the latter option and happily remove everything without any prompting.

Comment: @jlliagre - I did not realize that -f overrides -i. That does rather kill the idea. But it's what I love about SO - lots of smart people sharing what they know (and sometimes, as it turns out, what they don't know...). Thanks!